# What argument do I pass to the get_task_logger() function of celery?

Tags: python, celery

The [celery 3.x docs on logging](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging) recommend to set up the task logger like so:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
```

When I do that, `CELERYD_TASK_LOG_FORMAT` is ignored and the log statements use `CELERYD_LOG_FORMAT` instead, where I cannot make use of `%(task_name)s` and `%(task_id)s`.

My task is in a module `tasks` in my app `myapp`. Therefore, `__name__` is `myapp.tasks`.

I assume the problem are these lines in `celery/utils/log.py`:

```
def get_task_logger(name):
    logger = get_logger(name)
    if logger.parent is logging.root:
        logger.parent = task_logger
    return logger
```

So for whatever reason, the module passed to `get_task_logger()` has to be a first level module, otherwise the task logger is not attached. There is no comment explaining why this has to be the case (and I can't think of any reason why you would add this restriction, really). `__name__` doesn't work because it references a second level module.

Am I making a mistake or are the docs just wrong? If so, what am I supposed to pass to `get_task_logger()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2014-10-05, this is no longer the case. Passing `__name__` now seems to work fine ([current implementation](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/6ea6f24558df8037931345c1fbb299e947bfee46/celery/utils/log.py#L106)).

Just remember that your task loggers will still be forced to inherit from `celery.task`. Its parent logger `celery` does not propagate to the root logger by default, so you might want to define a logger for `celery.task` in your logging configuration.

Comment: Probably via a fix in billiard, see https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1404.